# pandas dataframe selecting the nan indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` with the following:

```
In [10]: df.index.unique()
Out[10]: array([u'DC', nan, u'BS', u'AB', u'OA'], dtype=object)
```

I can easily select out df.ix["DC"], df.ix["BS"], etc.  But I'm having trouble selecting the `nan` indexes.

```
df.ix[nan], df.ix["nan"], df.ix[np.nan] all won't work.
```

How do I select the rows with `nan` as the index?

Comment: in general it is highly discouraged to use nan in an index - if u have more than 1 nan your index is not unique and therefore lots of ops are much less efficient and complicated

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way would be to use `df.index.isnull()` to identify the location of the NaNs:

```
In [218]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], 'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'], 'val': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, index=['DC', np.nan, 'BS', 'AB', 'OA', np.nan]); df
Out[218]: 
     Date Name  val
DC      0    A    0
NaN     1    B    1
BS      2    C    2
AB      0    A    3
OA      1    B    4
NaN     2    C    5

In [219]: df.index.isnull()
Out[219]: array([False,  True, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Then you could select those rows using `df.loc`:

```
In [220]: df.loc[df.index.isnull()]
Out[220]: 
     Date Name  val
NaN     1    B    1
NaN     2    C    5
```

---

Note: My original answer used `pd.isnull(df.index)` instead of [Zero's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536133/pandas-dataframe-selecting-the-nan-indexes/25536283?noredirect=1#comment80135997_25536283), `df.index.isnull()`. It is better to use `df.index.isnull()` because for types of Indexes which can not hold NaNs, such as `Int64Index` and `RangeIndex`, the `isnull` method [returns an array of all False values *immediately*](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexes/base.py#L1824) instead of mindlessly checking each item in the index for NaN values.

Comment: Also, `df.loc[df.index.isnull()]` -- `isnull` method is added.

Comment: @Zero: Thanks for the improvement!

Comment: If we have to drop `nan` index rows, then `df.loc[df.index.notnull()]` helps!!